# Preg_replace: transforming string dates format

Tags: php, preg-replace, substring

I have big array fetched with diff `strpos()` and `substr()` :

```
$array[n] = ('Jan 23', 'From Jan 4 to Feb 1', 'Jul 5 to 10');
```

and I wish a process to convert it to:

```
$array[n] = ('2013-01-23','2013-01-04/2013-02-01','2013-07-05/2013-07-10);
```

Thanks for your help.
I plan to use `strpos()` to get the date string into the array.
after that, I plan to explode the date array, then perform a `foreach($date as $index => $value)`, if I can cast it to string then it´s a date, and I could use two digits, for months match with monthly names. and then form the desired string.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: I think preg_replace is most inefficient way to do this. I think you should look for better method.

Comment: Have you considered what happends when a start date will be 25 December, and end date 1 January? There is no year given...

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use instead [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function and [date_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-format.php) function? It can be very difficult to handle all the possible formats with regular expressions and string parsing.

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('your_string'));
```

Comment: Without any example code, this is more suited as a comment, and not an answer, especially as it is worded as a question.